# Test Smart Contract with arguments in constructor with truffle

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I want to test smart contract with parameter in constructor but have error.
Here is my smart contract and test files:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.7.0;

contract Test {
    string public test;
    constructor(string memory _test) public {
        test = _test;
    }
}
```

const Test = artifacts.require("Test");

```
contract('Test', (accounts) => {
  it('should init', async () => {
  
    const instance = await Test.new("test");
    const result = await instance.test;
    assert.equal("test", result, "info is not equals");
  });
});
```

And log:

```
Error: while migrating Test: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:68:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:55:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:171:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.runAll (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:114:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:79:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/testing/Test.js:109:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/test/index.js:192:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:136:1)
Truffle v5.1.64 (core: 5.1.64)
Node v12.16.3
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to create an instance of a contract via `new Test("test")`?

Comment: Not sure it is related, because in the log you can see that it is related to Migration

Answer (score 2):

Your forgot to pass the transaction params including the sender (deployer) adddres.

```
const instance = await Test.new("test");
```

shoud be

```
const txParams = {
    from: accounts[0]
};
const instance = await Test.new("test", txParams);
```

More info on the `new()` function: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#-code-mycontract-new-arg1-arg2-tx-params-code-

Comment: Is it still needed to use an `await web3.eth.getAccounts();` if the contract callback provides an accounts return value (`contract("Escrow", accounts => { ... })`)? See [reference](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57910/how-to-test-contract-with-multiple-accounts-addresses-in-truffle)

Comment: @Ndrslmpk Good point, it's not needed. I removed the duplicate from my answer.